# jquery autocomplete returned values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I am using a couple jQuery autocomplete functions on a view to retrive CustomerName and CustomerID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#CustomerByName').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Cases/FindByName",
                type: "GET",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    searchText: request.term,
                    maxResults: 10
                },
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return {
                            label: item.CustomerName,
                            value: item.CustomerName,
                            id: item.CustomerID
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 1,
        select: function (event, ui) {
            $('#CustomerID').val(ui.item.id);
        },
    });
});
```

The success response gives me label, value, id. Is there any way to access the other fields return in the json data? In this case the entire table is return as json.

Thanks

Comment: You got tags, no need to add them to the title.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't understand what you mean though. I am new to jquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify the success function to include any extra fields you want to use in select e.g.

```
success: function (data) {
              response($.map(data, function (item) {
                  return {
                      label: item.CustomerName,
                      value: item.CustomerName,
                      id: item.CustomerID,
                      // extra fields go here
                      address: item.CustomerAddress
                  }
              }));
          }
```

Then you can access them in the select function like this:

```
select: function (event, ui) {
    $('#CustomerID').val(ui.item.id);
    alert('CustomerAddress is ' + ui.item.address);
},
```